# Hibernate custom finder SQL query doesn't return OneToMany relation

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, annotations

I have a `User` class that has a `@OneToMany` `List<Address>` property. Hibernate has created a join table between user and address. When a user logs in, I look for the user with a custom SQL query;

`select * from user where username = ? and password = ?`

This obviously returns all the other fields of user but not the `List<Address>`. Is there a way in Hibernate to also return the relational data without using custom queries?

Could I load the user through the custom query above, pull its ID, and then reload the user so that Hibernate loads all the fields? Are there any better ways?

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @GenericGenerator(name = "incremental", strategy = "increment")
    private Long userID;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_address", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "userID"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "addressID"))
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NonVisual
    public Long addressID;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using HQL as below:

```
String queryString = "select u from User u left join u.addresses "+
                     "where u.username = :userName and u.password = :password";
```

**EDIT:** Sample code to execute HQL

```
String queryString = "select u from User u left join u.addresses "+
                     "where u.username = :userName and u.password = :password";
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString );
query.setParameter("userName", userNameValue);
query.setParameter("password", passwordValue);
List<User> users = query.list();
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You mentioned `I have a User class that has a @OneToMany List<Address>`, right? What is the field name of `List<Address>`? I just used that as address. Need to change the query accordingly.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis then you need to update your user entity class by using @ JoinTable annotation and use a hql as Yogendra described. Please see this example, I am not able to test functionality but should give you an idea and in google more resources: http://tadtech.blogspot.cz/2007/09/hibernate-annotation-one-to-many-join.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That is fine. I updated the answer. Try using the updated query. It should load addresses along with user.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think we are going in two directions. As I said, its HQL not SQL. `u` is referring your `User` entity object and it has `addresses` as the mapped field. Also since I am using named paramters, the the params using the name as `query.setParameter("userName", userNameValue);query.setParameter("password", passwordValue);`. I updated the answer.

Comment: That worked finally. I was using session.createSQLQuery... Thank you. Accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You have lazy property association on by default, and you need to call `getAddresses()` for the user to retrieve a lazy collection.

Collections require a little more work to initialize - you could of course, do it manually by traversing the entire collection, but it is perhaps better to call on the Hibernate utility class to do that for you. The `Hibernate.initialize` method takes an object as an argument, and initializes any lazy associations (this includes collections). So, if you wanted to fully initialize the user, and then fully initialize the collection of addresses:

```
Object[] userObject; // the object returned by the query.
User u = new User(userObject); // create the user
Hibernate.initialize(u); // initializes user
Hibernate.initialize(u.getAddresses()); // pass the lazy collection into the session to be initialized.
```

Comment: Without the code posted after my answer I used `LAZY` fetch type for association used by default.

Comment: The problem in my use case is that the User is saved in the http session. In later request, we might want to pull an address from the user. If the hibernate session is closed, this gives exceptions.

Comment: Why the hibernate session is closed?

Comment: Because my request ended. I clean up to return resources to pool. Anyway, in a future http request, a new thread will handle it and getCurrentSession() won't work anymore so I can't find the hibernate session I was using before.